# are kafka streams logically the same as a polling kafla consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

There are at least two ways for a consumer to receive messages from Kafka,

1. by polling
2. by streams

Given polling is bad (too frequent and you use CPU on consumer and/or broker, too slow and you introduce latency), Im wondering if streams are better (ignoring the extra streams stuff like tables).   The question is do you lose anything by using streams? Is streams the same as a polling consumer in terms of features?

The application simply consumes messages, it doesnt need to know message history and doesnt put the results back onto another topic, so in theory doesnt need streams, but trying to avoid polling.

When using MS service bus, you can write azure functions (servless), and the function gets called (notified) by each message as an event.  Im wondering if I can simulate this model in kafka using streams to avoid polling?

Comment: Kafka Streams is an API over the consumer API. It still calls the poll function internally... Note: There are other frameworks like Spring, Quarkus, or Vertx for KafkaConsumer that hide the poll function from the end-user

Answer (score 0):

In Streams, you lose the ability to finely control consumer pause/resume (if needed) and cannot perform manual offset commits or seeking.

> polling is bad (too frequent and you use CPU on consumer and/or broker, too slow and you introduce latency

Streams API is still polling records from the broker; there is no alternative in Kafka. If you have latency, you may need to adjust the Consumer configuration values.